# necesito hacer que imprima las palabras que empiecen con a,e,i,o,u de una lista y pasarlos a un archivo .txt

Tags: python

He intentado ya todo y no puedo hacerlo

```
palabras = ['RECOMPENSAR','LEGISLAR','DESEMBALLESTAR','CONFLUIR','CHICLEAR','ENCAVARSE','BARBOTAR','PERFILAR','PRETENDER','AMUCHAR','LIBRAR','SOLTAR','ESGONZAR','OVALAR','ALEBRARSE','DESALMENAR','ENCALAR','VIGORAR','MURMULLAR','PREINSCRIBIR','PINTEAR','INFESTAR','DOMEÑAR','PERVIVIR','PLAGIAR','MALQUISTAR','TITIRITEAR','JAQUEAR','BORDEAR','ARRISCAR']
    arch1=open("A.txt","w")
    arch2=open("E.txt","w")
    arch3=open("I.txt","w")
    arch4=open("O.txt","w")
    arch5=open("U.txt","w")
    arch6=open("C.txt","w")
    for let in lista:
            arch.write(if let[0]==A +"\n")
            arch2.write(if let[0]==E +"\n")
            arch3.write(if  let[0]==I +"\n")
            arch4.write(if let[0]==O +"\n")
            arch5.write(if let[0]==U +"\n")
    arch.close()
    arch2.close()
    arch3.close()
    arch4.close()
    arch5.close()
    arch6.close()
```

Comment: Buenas, la pregunta no esta clara y tu codigo nisiquiera se acerca a ella, el codigo parece tener como objetivo algo muy diferente, por favor, aclara la pregunta y los objetivos

Answer (score 1):

analizando la estructura de tu programa interpreto que necesitas guardar la lista de palabras dependiendo de la vocal con la que empieza, entonces tendrías al final un archivo de todas las vocales con la lista de palabras adentro.

Como puedes ver tambien soy nuevo en esta comunidad, sin embargo te aconsejo que estructures mejor tus consultas y que coloque títulos claros y precisos, ya en el cuerpo de tu mensaje puedes explicar mejor tu situación, esto le facilitara al resto de miembros el comprender tu problema y ayudarte de una mejor manera.

Volviendo al programa lo que necesitas es recorrer la lista de las palabras y analizar si la primer letra de la palabra es una vocal, si se cumple la condición puedes almacenar esa palabra dentro de otra lista, luego procedes a almacenar las palabras dentro del archivo que corresponda.

```
palabras = ['RECOMPENSAR','LEGISLAR','DESEMBALLESTAR','CONFLUIR','CHICLEAR','ENCAVARSE','BARBOTAR','PERFILAR','PRETENDER','AMUCHAR','LIBRAR','SOLTAR','ESGONZAR','OVALAR','ALEBRARSE','DESALMENAR','ENCALAR','VIGORAR','MURMULLAR','PREINSCRIBIR','PINTEAR','INFESTAR','DOMEÑAR','PERVIVIR','PLAGIAR','MALQUISTAR','TITIRITEAR','JAQUEAR','BORDEAR','ARRISCAR']

vocales = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
empieza_con_consonante = []

for vocal in vocales:
  empieza_con_vocal = []
  for palabra in palabras:
    if palabra[0] == vocal:
      empieza_con_vocal.append(palabra)
    else:
      empieza_con_consonante.append(palabra)

  if empieza_con_vocal:
    with open('%s' % vocal, 'w') as output:
      output.write('\n'.join(empieza_con_vocal))
      output.close()

if empieza_con_consonante:
    with open('consonante', 'w') as output:
      output.write('\n'.join(empieza_con_consonante))
      output.close()
```

Recuerda, siempre antes de escribir cualquier línea de código, primero analiza que es lo que debes hacer y divide en problemas mas pequeños, de esa manera se hace mucho mas fácil encontrar las soluciones, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias!